# Awk command result into array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

i've a text file who contains this :

```
Hello 4
Bye 2
Toto 2
```

And i want to put the first string of each lines into MyArray1, and the integer into another one MyArray2.

I wrote this, but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

countline=$(awk '{ print $1 }'  test | wc -l)


for ((i=0; i<$countline ;i=i+1))

    do

        MyArray1[$i]=awk '{ print $1 }'  test
done


for ((i=0; i<$countline ;i=i+1))

    do

        MyArray2[$i]=awk '{ print $2 }'  test
done
```

Please help me.

Comment: Note, this is simpler and faster: `countline=$(wc -l < test)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
MyArray1=( $(awk '{ print $1 }' test) )
MyArray2=( $(awk '{ print $2 }' test) )
```

You don't need to iterate and loop on awk's output and can directly create your arrays as shown above.

Answer (score 4):

This would do it:

```
while read -r f1 f2; do 
    ary1+=("$f1")
    ary2+=("$f2")
done < file
```

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${ary1[@]}"
Hello
Bye
Toto

$ printf "%s\n" "${ary2[@]}"
4
2
2
```

Or you can use `cut`

```
arryone=( $(cut -d ' ' -f1 file) )
arrytwo=( $(cut -d ' ' -f2 file) )
```

Comment: Just to point out how odd `bash` arrays are, the following works, too: `while read -r ary1[i] ary2[i]; do (( i++ )); done` (as long as `i` is 0 or unset to begin with).

Comment: Ahh @chepner now that is beautiful! Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: +1 for a solution that only reads through the file once... and with no extra external processes...